# Weblogic SOAP service deployment errors reporting two ports in war when there is only one

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, weblogic

I have a weblogic server with a cluster of two SOA servers.
I am deploying a servlet to this server with a SOAP servlet created with the JDeveloper wizard (Create Java Web Service from WSDL -> Java EE 1.5, with support for JAX-WS Annotations)
It is deployed as a standalone application.

During the development of the application I have changed the WSDL in various ways including changing the port name.

I have gone into the weblogic interface, deleted the previous instalisation and re-deployed through JDeveloper. I get the following error message:

[08:44:59 PM] weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error encountered during prepare phase of deploying WebService module 'RJMTestBannerAdapter.war'. Two port in the callBannerService(WebserviceDescriptionBean) has the same name {http://ic.ac.uk/AIAMetaData/AIAComponents/ApplicationObjectLibrary/Banner/V1/APIJavaAdapter/BannerAPIJavaAdapterWsdl}callBanner.

It is complaining that there is two ports in the application with the same name. But there isn't.
I have inspected the .war file that JDeveloper produces
The WEB-INF/web.xml has a single entry for the service
The WEB-INF/weblogic.xml is also correct and just specifies the context-root.

I have determined that somewhere in the weblogic servers there must be something with the end point that is not being cleared away when I delete the application.
I have checked the weblogic console user interface, gone through the list of web applications and services and confirmed it is not there.

Does the weblogic server have a deployment plan file or something simular it is picking up while deploying? If so where would this deployment plan be?

I don't think it is important but here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>callBanner</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ic.ac.uk.ic.rjmtest.banner.adapter.gen.main.Main_ptImpl12</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>callBanner</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/callBanner</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also this is the weblogic.xml that appears in the war file. (It is not in my project but JDeveloper must generate it)

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd" xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <context-root>RJMTestBannerAdapter</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I have also inspected the WSDL and there is only a single port.

Comment: Have you tried deploying application without cluster or any other environment? It will point you to the direction whether there is a issue with the server/ server cleanup.

Comment: I haven't tried this but it is a good idea. I will do this and feedback the result

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.

When I used JDeveloper to regenerate the classes for the service I must have changed the name somehow. This resulted in new java being built.

As I didn't delete the classes or deploy directory the old ones were still there in my war file. So I was trying to deploy two even though my .java files didn't reflect this.

Deleting the classes and deploy directories then recompiling resolved the issue.

This post might be useful for anyone else who hits this error!